# is it possible to link attribute enumerations (Types) to objects in another module in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors, requirements-management

I have a DOORS module A that have an enumurated attribute and have numerous objects with each have this enumerated attribute set to one or more enums. i want to define these enums as objects in another DOORS module B. the goal is to be able to query in **module B** all module A objects that have the associated enum set.

i can do this by linking all module A objects to their respective module B object(enums). however, this requires manually establishing the links every time module A objects is changed.

is there an alternate method that is maintenance free? *like linking Attributes Types to objects*

`DOORS Client version:   9.7.2.6`